# Add network location in Windows 7 with "Explicit FTP over TLS"

Tags: windows-7, ftp

I know how to add an FTP network location in Windows 7, but does Windows 7 support the "explicit FTP over TLS" configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but something like [Swish](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/map-network-location-over-ssh-sftp-in-windows-explorer/) may do what you want (has an explorer extension).